# BETWEEN condition select only single row Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

Inputs:

```
:startPrice = 180
:targetPrice = 300
```

In database I have a price column and need to find all rows where price column lay beetwen 180 and 300.

Price values in DB:

```
 price = 270
 price = 278
```

So how we can see the query what I wrote below must fetch rhese two rows, but I getting only first(270).

Can somebody explain me why BETWEEN condition fetch only one row from DB? Here is DB query  builder:

```
$query = $result = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('t')
        ->from('VputiTripBundle:Trip', 't');
             $query
               ->andWhere('t.price > :startPrice')
                ->andWhere('t.price < :targetPrice');
            $parameters = [
                'startPrice' => $startPrice,
                'targetPrice' => $targetPrice,
            ];
        $query->setParameters($parameters)
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
         ->getResult();
```

Query string:

```
'SELECT t FROM VputiTripBundle:Trip t WHERE t.price > :startPrice AND t.price < :targetPrice'
```

Comment: Are you sure there is more data in the DB that should match? Also you're not setting the parameters to the query

Comment: thwo rows in database with price 270 and 278. I found beetwen 250 and 300.

Comment: what is the result if you let the option "MaxResults" out?

Comment: @KhorneHoly, the same... single element(object) in array

Comment: That's really weird.. Are the Prices stored as `integer`? Are you giving the parameters as `string`? Else i'd make an issue by the github of symfony2 or Doctrine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$query = $queryBuilder
        ->select('t')
        ->from('VputiTripBundle:Trip', 't')
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->between('t.price', ':startPrice', ':targetPrice'))
        ->setParameters([
            'startPrice' => $startPrice,
            'targetPrice' => $targetPrice
        ])
        ->getQuery();

        $query->setMaxResults(10);

        return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I already try something like this, but still fetching the only one(first) row from DB.

Comment: @Panzer_Commander I think you should post your table structure, entity structure and action/manager also.. I'm sure problem is not in db query..

Comment: It is not necessary) I reload my project by clear cache, droping schema, create it, update it, and all works! I dont know how but... thanks all guys)